# "az pipelines run variables" not working the way i expected

Tags: azure-devops, az

i have a branch in git with a .yaml build file which has a script to simply print out the value of the variable declared in the .yaml

if i run the command: `az pipelines run --id 999 --variables "myvar=myvar"` I expected the variable to change as I am injecting it. it doesnt.

am i misunderstanding what this switch does?  if so, what is it supposed to do and/or how can i achieve my goal?

i tried
i tried
i dont understand these SO "quality standards" <= (this line allowed me to save the post)

Comment: Did you get this working? I'm running into the same issue. I see the variable (parameter, really) being posted if I use `--debug`

Comment: @DylanBerry Sorry, I never did.  I ending up changing my perspective on the solution.   I started using variable groups instead.  I am able to change what is in a variable group using the CLI (i think - it was a long time ago) - but even then I abandoned it as I found other ways of achieving what I wanted.

Comment: if you're interested, I used the rest api to get this working the way I wanted: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli-extensions/issues/2974#issuecomment-782040239

Comment: @DylanBerry Thanks for that.  Very useful to know!

Answer (score -4):

For **[az pipelines variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-devops/pipelines/variable?view=azure-cli-latest#ext-azure-devops-az-pipelines-variable-update)** ,there are  four commands

- `az pipelines variable create` Add a variable to a pipeline.
- `az pipelines variable delete` Delete a variable from pipeline.
- `az pipelines variable list` List the variables in a pipeline.
- `az pipelines variable update`Update a variable in a pipeline.

You should use `az pipelines variable update` command to update a variable in a pipeline.

Command sample:

```
az pipelines variable update --name
```

Comment: but what if these variables are in a .yaml file rather than the pipeline?  the original question was really how do i make the "-variables" switch on the `az pipelines run` command work as I couldnt get it to do anything with a pipeline variable or with a .yaml variable.
i have since managed to use multi stage .yml files to do something respectable and will be looking to use your idea by way of variable groups.  I thin kyou are right and i should change a pipeline/group variable then trigger the pipeline with `run`.  i will be back after i try this all, thanks

Comment: @Kam Any luck with your experiments?
Edit: Found your answer above. will try that out.

Comment: @RajneeshGadge i moved away from it all and went to variable templates, expressions and conditions.  what are you trying to achieve.  declaratively.

Comment: @Kam for now I am sorted, using the following approach:
`az pipelines run --id ${PIPELINE_ID} ${parameters}` 

My use case was to run an azure devops pipeline from within an different pipeline supplying multiple parameters.  The above works fine and solved my problem.